# VBA Visual Basic, Array stops giving results after 32,768 rows, Combination Code w/ recursion

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a code I use to make Fantasy Sports combinations in excel and it works absolutely perfect up to about 32,000 rows. When I have refined results under that, no problem at all, but sometimes I wanted combinations for 50 to 100k rows and it will not suffice.

So, my initial thought was I have some variable named Integer but I do not see one and I am truly out of ideas.

Below is a picture of how it looks when it is WORKING or 'combining':
[image]

Below is a picture of how it looks when it is NOT WORKING or 'not combining':
[image]

The is the Array I use for the working one:
[image] (Selected Cells, Columns Used)

And as long as the results are under the 32,000 rows it works, when I make that range of cells more like a group of 100 cells, it shows the NOT WORKING result.

Here is the respective code I am using:

```
Public result() As Variant
------

Function Combinations(rng As Range, n As Long)
rng1 = rng.Value

ReDim result(n - 1, 0)

Call Recursive(rng1, n, 1, 0)

ReDim Preserve result(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2) - 1)
Combinations = Application.Transpose(result)

End Function
------
Function Recursive(r As Variant, c As Long, d As Long, e As Long)

Dim f As Long


For f = d To UBound(r, 1)

result(e, UBound(result, 2)) = r(f, 1)

If e = (c - 1) Then

ReDim Preserve result(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2) + 1)

For g = 0 To UBound(result, 1)
result(g, UBound(result, 2)) = result(g, UBound(result, 2) - 1)
Next g
Else
Call Recursive(r, c, f + 1, e + 1)
End If

Next f

End Function
```

If anyone has any ideas of how to expand it beyond 32,000 rows or if I am missing some variable that does not allow it to hold any more data, let me know.

Thank you so very much!

Comment: 32,767 is a common limit for several Excel items.  [See this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Try calling your function from a VBA Sub instead of from the worksheet - that may give you more information.

Comment: Oh, I am going to give that a shot thank you!

Comment: Please see:  http://excelmatters.com/2016/03/08/transpose-bug-in-2013-and-2016/

Comment: ... and use `Option Explicit` !

Answer (score 0):

I would treat this as a combination problem, like picking n from a certain number of possible lotto numbers.

```
Sub Combinations()

Dim Combo()

Data = Array("Tim", "Tom", "Debbie", "Sally", "Sam", "Todd", "Ted", "Mike", "Dan", "Matt")
DataLen = UBound(Data) + 1

Do
   Size = Val(InputBox("Enter Size from 1 to " & DataLen))

Loop While Size <= 0 And Size > DataLen

ReDim Combo(Size)
Level = 1
RowCount = 1
ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
Call Recursive(Data, Combo(), Level, Size, RowCount)

End Sub
Sub Recursive(Data, Combo, Level, Size, RowCount)

DataLen = UBound(Data) + 1
'make combination
For Count = (Combo(Level - 1) + 1) To _
   DataLen - (Size - Level)

   Combo(Level) = Count
   If Level = Size Then
      For ColCount = 1 To Size
         Cells(RowCount, ColCount) = _
            Data(Combo(ColCount) - 1)
      Next ColCount
      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Else
      Call Recursive(Data, Combo, Level + 1, Size, RowCount)
   End If
Next Count
End Sub
```

I picked 3 names from the list and got the following combinations.

[image]

I'm not sure how you're getting over 32k combinations, unless you have a heck of a lot of unique names.  I suppose 60+ unique names would get you to over 32k rows.

Comment: Don't underesimate that! If sequence matters 35 elements lead to 35 * 34* 33 = 38080 combinations.

Comment: Didn't try, just evaled. If I had to do this I would think about my DB do the work (Join the list 3 times on not equal dhould do it).

Comment: Of course you can use SQL for this.  SELECT distinct t1.[Id],t2.[CategoryName],t3.[CompanyName]
  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Book] t1,
  [NORTHWND].[dbo].[CATEGORIES] t2,
  [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Customers] t3

Or, R, or Python.  You have lots of options.  For me, Excel would probably be the last option for a problem like this.

Comment: Your recursion is fast but missing a worksheet reference. Don't rely pn `ActiveSheet` I had put your code to a Standard-Module`and it failed writing

Answer (score 0):

@PortlandRunner is on the right track, I wrote my own transpose function because of the limit on the Application.Transpose.  Pretty simple, from memory it goes something like this:

```
Public Function TransposeArray(byval arrIn as variant) as variant

Dim arrOut as variant

Dim lngRow as long
Dim lngCol as long

Redim arrout(lbound arrin,2) to ubound(ArrIn,2),lbound(arrIn,1) to ubound(arrIn,1))

For lngrow =lbound(arrIn,1) to ubound(arrIn,1)
    For lngCol =lbound(arrIn,2) to ubound(arrIn,2)
        Arrout(lngCol,lngrow) = arrin(lngrow, lngCol)
    Next lngCol 
Next lngrow 

TransposeArray = arrout

End function
```